Does this optimization problem have an explicit solution?
Let $\lambda > 0, \eta \in [0, \pi/2]$ and consider the maximization problem
$$
\sup_{0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2} 
\cos^2(\theta + \eta) 
\Big\{
\frac{1}{\lambda + \sin^2(\theta)} + 
\frac{1}{\lambda + \cos^2(\theta)} 
\Big\} 
$$
Question:
Is it possible to characterize the optimal $\theta$ (or the value of the supremum) as a function of $\lambda, \eta$?
One obvious case is $\eta = 0$, then differentiation shows that the optimal choice is $\theta = 0$ and the maximal value is $1/\lambda + 1/(\lambda+1)$.
Similarly if $\eta = \pi/2$, then $\theta = \pi/2$ is optimal and the maximal value is again $1/\lambda + 1/(\lambda + 1)$.

Roughly calculating shows the maximum occurs either $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \pi/2$.

What do you mean by "roughly calculating"?

Let $\cos\theta = \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}, \sin \theta = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \cos \eta = \frac{2s}{1+s^2}, \sin\eta = \frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2}$. Use Maple to calculate $f(0) - f(\theta)$ and $f(\pi/2) - f(\theta)$ (two cases.).
